# Find only the rows which have data on related table in YIi2

Tags: yii2

I have two table: "Users" which contain user data, and "Posts" which contain user's post. Each user can have many posts.

Users

- id
- full_name

Posts

- post_no
- post_content
- id_user

What I want to do is hide users which has no post, so I tried to join the tables in my search model:

```
public function search($params) {
    $query = Users::find->joinWith(['posts']);
}
```

but unfortunately, users with no post still shown.

Comment: Use `innerJoinWith()`

Comment: @Insane Skull I tried your suggestion and changed it into: $query = Users::find->innerJoinWIth(['posts]); but still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql `WHERE NOT NULL` syntax

```
$query = Users::find->joinWith(['posts'])->where(['not', ['posts.post_no' => null]]);
```

WHERE NOT NULL alternative syntax for Yii2:

```
->where(['IS NOT', 'posts.post_no', null]);

->where(['<>', 'posts.post_no', null]);

->having(['posts.post_no' => 'NOT NULL']);
```

Please Check the official documentation here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where()-detail

Comment: glad to help :-)